# Bootstrap table both responsive and table header fixed with horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have created bootstrap table but i am unable to make to both 
responsive and scrollable

For scroll-able i fixed table's body height and reduce scroll width

What i want is 
if number of columns increases it table will scroll (just like normal bootstrap responsive)  i.e. both thead and tbody will scroll
and then vertical scroll will work

Resulting CSS should work in all devices(ex mac)

```css
th, tr {
    text-align: center;
}

th {
    position: relative !important;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
}

tbody {
    display: flex;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

thead, tbody tr {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    position: relative !important;
    /* even columns width , fix width of table too*/
}

thead {
    width: calc(100% - 1em);/* scrollbar is average 1em/16px width, remove it from thead width */
}

table {
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
    <th>D</th>
    <th>E</th>
    <th>F</th>

    <th>G</th>
    <th>H</th>
    <th>I</th>
    <th>J</th>
    <th>K</th>
    <th>L</th>
    <th>M</th>
    <th>N</th>
    <th>O</th>
    <th>P</th>
  </thead>

  <tr>
    <td> a </td>
    <td> b </td>
    <td> c </td>
    <td> d </td>
    <td> e </td>
    <td> f </td>
    <td> g </td>
    <td> h </td>
    <td> i </td>
    <td> j </td>
    <td>k </td>
    <td> l </td>
    <td>m</td>
    <td> n </td>
    <td>o</td>
    <td> p </td>
  </tr>

</table>

<div>
```